# Python - XML parse/Import process breaks with string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, xml, parsing

I'm running a XML import process but for some reason I always fail if not all fields are set/filled with data (at least I assume that at the moment). For some reason it works with one given dateset and with a smaller one it does not ...

Please have a look at my code snipped:

```
def get_plist_names(name_dict):
    return [o["string"] for o in (name_dict if isinstance(name_dict, list) else [name_dict])]

....
        if 'iTunMOVI' in clean_result['format']['tags']:
        xml_parse = xmltodict.parse(clean_result['format']['tags']['iTunMOVI'])  # Parse given XML data to dict.
        dump_json = json.dumps(xml_parse)
        plist_metadata = json.loads(dump_json)
        print(plist_metadata)
        dict = plist_metadata['plist']['dict']
        print(dict["array"])
        zipped = zip(dict["key"], dict["array"])
        print(zipped)
        result = {"directors": [], "producers": [], "cast": [], "screenwriters": []} | {k: get_plist_names(v["dict"]) for k, v in zipped}
        directors_value = (', '.join(result.get("directors", None)))
        producers_value = (', '.join(result.get("producers", None)))
        cast_value = (', '.join(result.get("cast", None)))
        screenwriters_value = (', '.join(result.get("screenwriters", None)))
        if 'studio' in plist_metadata['plist']['dict']['key']:
            studio_value = plist_metadata['plist']['dict']['string']
```

which outputs the following error:

```
   File "/app/Core/tasks.py", line 172, in import_descriptor
     {k: get_plist_names(v["dict"]) for k, v in zipped}
   File "/app/Core/tasks.py", line 172, in <dictcomp>
     {k: get_plist_names(v["dict"]) for k, v in zipped}
 TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

when the following data is given at "plist_metadata = json.loads(dump_json)":

```
{'plist': {'@version': '1.0', 'dict': {'key': 'directors', 'array': {'dict': {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sara Kelly-Garcia'}}}}}
```

or as parsed:

```
{'key': 'directors', 'array': {'dict': {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sara Kelly-Garcia'}}}
```

dict["array"] contains:

```
{'dict': {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sara Kelly-Garcia'}}
```

The thing now is that if for example a bigger dataset is given at plist_metadata = json.loads(dump_json) it works fine:

```
{'plist': {'@version': '1.0', 'dict': {'key': ['cast', 'directors', 'producers', 'screenwriters', 'studio'], 'array': [{'dict': [{'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sabine Timoteo'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Muho Nölke'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sangha Gemeinschaft'}]}, {'dict': {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Werner Penzel'}}, {'dict': [{'key': 'name', 'string': 'Werner Penzel'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Peter Guyer'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Madeleine Corbat'}]}, {'dict': [{'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sabine Timoteo'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Werner Penzel'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Ayako Mogi'}]}], 'string': 'Some Studio Company'}}}
```

or as parsed:

```
 {'key': ['cast', 'directors', 'producers', 'screenwriters', 'studio'], 'array': [{'dict': [{'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sabine Timoteo'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Muho Nölke'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sangha Gemeinschaft'}]}, {'dict': {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Werner Penzel'}}, {'dict': [{'key': 'name', 'string': 'Werner Penzel'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Peter Guyer'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Madeleine Corbat'}]}, {'dict': [{'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sabine Timoteo'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Werner Penzel'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Ayako Mogi'}]}], 'string': 'Some Studio Company'}
```

again at dict["array"]:

```
[{'dict': [{'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sabine Timoteo'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Muho Nölke'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sangha Gemeinschaft'}]}, {'dict': {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Werner Penzel'}}, {'dict': [{'key': 'name', 'string': 'Werner Penzel'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Peter Guyer'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Madeleine Corbat'}]}, {'dict': [{'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sabine Timoteo'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Werner Penzel'}, {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Ayako Mogi'}]}]
```

Can somebody please give me a hint why it works for the bigger one and not for the smaller one. doesn't ".get" handle this out if a field does not exist?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Barmar What do you mean? zipped = zip(dict["key"], dict["array"])

Comment: Still does not explain why its work with one of the given dataset and not with the other, or do I miss something here? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name. You're overwriting the built-in function name.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the code you posted. Is all that code part of the `get_plist_names()` function?

Comment: I guess not, since the first line of `get_plist_names()` is a `return` statement.

Comment: @Barmar get_plist_names() is outside. Its just a function call

Comment: I see that now, I was misled by your original indentation.

Comment: @mzjn content has been added to question. my Bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first dataset has:

```
dict == {'key': 'directors', 'array': {'dict': {'key': 'name', 'string': 'Sara Kelly-Garcia'}}}
```

so `zip(dict['key'], dict['array'])` loops over the characters of `'directors'` and the keys of the `array` dictionary, producing

```
[('d', 'dict')]
```

Then in your dictionary comprehension, `k == 'd'` and `v == 'dict'`, so you get an error when you try to use `v["dict"]`.

Your code is expecting `dict['key']` and `dict['array']` to both be lists. It needs to check for this.

```
dict = plist_metadata['plist']['dict']
if not isinstance(dict['key'], list):
    dict['key'] = [dict['key']]
if not isinstance(dict['array'], list):
    dict['array'] = [dict['array']]
```

Comment: I was fuzzing around with this issue since days ... Again thanks for your help. really appreciate that! Now the import flow works without any breaks :D
Have a fine weekend